# How to fix Laravel eager loading not working with custom foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Listing and Sub_Category have a one to many relationship. Listing belongs to one sub_category and sub_category has many listings.

I have a column on my listings table 'sub_catgory_id' and I have also specified the foreign key in my relationship

```
Listing.php Model
public function sub_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sub_Category', 'sub_category_id', 'id');
}
```

Trying to get all listings associated with a sub category

```
return $sub_category = \App\Sub_Category::with('listing')->get()
```

I get this error => Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'listings.sub__category_id' in 'where clause'.

I know eloquent is checking for sub__category_id (double underscore) but I am already far into this project and would like to leave it as sub_category_id (single underscore). Any ideas about how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out a fix. You can camelCase your model. So in my case I renamed my model from Sub_Category to subCategory so eloquent checks sub_category_id.

Comment: It's common to have class name in PascalCase like `SubCategory` to comply with well PHP practice. Also you can keep your models' methods camel cased i.e. `subCategory()`.

Comment: You can still keep it with the old name and properly set the foreign key and id in relation will make it work

Comment: You set it good in Listing, but you called relation only from Category model, which is certainly not set properly.

Comment: @KeitelDOG it was set properly, the problem was the case the class was written in

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set like :

**1**.Listening.php:

```
public function sub_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sub_Category', 'id', 'sub_category_id');
}
```

2.Sub_Category.php :

```
public function listing()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Listening', 'sub_category_id','id');
}
```

By [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) in set Relationships we set first **foreign_key** then **local_key** like this (Example get from laravel website):

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Comment: Hi, for listing.php the foreign key is sub_category_id, for sub_category.php the foreign key is listing_id. You swapped both. The only fix I know of for now is to camelCase the class name to avoid double underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
1.Sub_Category.php(Model)

public function listimg() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Listening');
}

2.Contoller
$sub_category = \App\Sub_Category::with('listing')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the custom foreign key column you have pass two additional arguments for the function `hasMany('Model', 'fk', 'pk')` with the foreign key column name and the reference key column name.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    public function contents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'sub_cat_id', 'id');
    }
}
class Content extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'contents';
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('parent_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('app_id');
            $table->integer('cat_id');
            $table->bigInteger('sub_cat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('content_type');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('sub_cat_id')->references('id')->
            on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```